# Streaming large (200 MB) zip through PHP

Tags: php, stream, zip

I am creating an server-side api for my app. One of the steps requires the app do download a very large zip file from my server, but it can't be done by just downloading `http://mydomain.com/file.zip`. My app passes some authentication headers and other safety stuff which **must be processed by a php script** (e.g. `http://mydomain.com/download.php?auth=foo&key=value&etc`)

I have done this kind of thing earlier using images:

```
<?php

$can_download = /* some complicated auth stuff */

if($can_download) {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    echo file_get_contents('image.jpg');
}

?>
```

My question is: **can it be done with 200+ MB zip file?** I know I have to modify headers somehow and probably use some advanced php functions, but I couldn't find any tutorial neither here, on Stack Overflow, nor anywhere else.

**Edit:** I also have to be able to *resume* my downloads, because it's very likely that user would quit the app, though it should be able to resume the download (e.g. from 47%). Can it be done?

---

For those looking for the answer: the correct function is **[readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)** and 'resuming' problem can be solved using **[this custom function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php#86244)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct function to use in this instance is [`readfile`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php).

The given code would encounter problems because it unnecessarily loads the file contents into memory before forwarding them to the browser. This does not help performance, and can easily result in running out of memory.

Comment: be careful that this solution, although optimal in resource usage, does not offer support for HTTP ranges, which might be useful for very large file downloads which can be interrupted for a variety of reasons

Comment: @SirDarius You mean that I can't simply 'resume' my download?

Comment: @AdrianKahsivskyy readfile offers not support for specifying a range in the file, and the associated HTTP request header is not automatically supported anyways, see http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.readfile.php#86244 for an attempt at solving this problem

Comment: @AdrianKahsivskyy: You can't. If you wanted to do that, you 'd have to parse the [`Range`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header) request header and then manually work with `fseek`/`fread` to provide just the requested part of the content. Your responses must also include the [`Accept-Ranges`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#accept-ranges-response-header) and [`Content-Range`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#content-range-response-header) headers.

Comment: @Jon Looks like http://php.net/manual/fr/function.readfile.php#86244 solves that problem. :)

Comment: @AdrianKahsivskyy yes, it is going to be less efficient than readfile though. The best approach would be to detect whether the whole file is requested, use readfile in that case, and fall back to the "smartReadFile" solution in case of partial request.

Comment: @SirDarius Ok, I understand. But how can I detect it?

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks :D One last question: the author of `smartReadFile` says that "it can be slow for big files to read by fread". What does he mean? My zip is over 200MB. Should I still keep looking for a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, however you want to use something like `readfile` instead. The reason being is that `file_get_contents` reads the entire file into memory before passing it to the client.